# VLOOKUP return NA in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula, vlookup

[image]

If I in some cell write:

`=VLOOKUP(A1,B3:C6,1,FALSE)`

It returns  `#N/A`

Why does VLOOKUP not work?

An alternative to this function will also be accepted.

Comment: It should work and return `CT`, not `#N/A`. Can you change `CT` in A1 to something else and see whether it works? It could be that it is written in cyrillic? It is a common prank as the letters look 100% the same, but they are quite different.

Comment: I tried to play with it. It seems it doesn't care what I type in cell A1, it keeps returning ```#N/A```.

Comment: Try to rewrite the data in the table, it could be that there is a space before the values in the name column.

Comment: Doesn't work either.

Comment: Strange. It would be a good idea to evaluate a bit the formula. See this https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/evaluate-a-nested-formula-one-step-at-a-time-59a201ae-d1dc-4b15-8586-a70aa409b8a7

Comment: It surely is odd. I will try. Thank you for your suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your formula seems fine and should work. Just change `column_index`to 2. Try-

```
=VLOOKUP(A1,B3:C6,2,FALSE)
```

[image]

Alternatively you can use `Index()/Match()` like-

```
=INDEX(C3:C6,MATCH(A1,B3:B6,0))
```

Comment: Of course with a 2. The VLOOKUP still return ```#N/A```, but the combination of index and match works, thank you.

Comment: @User123456789 If you have `Office365` then you can use single `XLOOKUP()` function.

Comment: Sadly, I don't have Office365

Comment: @User123456789 No issue. Index, Match is good enough.